# Django Rest Framework Pagination How to fix ( name 'pagination' is not defined )

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to paginate a search Query. All imports seem to be in the right place, but it keeps telling me that error. "pagination.PaginationSerializer is not defined".  I don't understand why? since I imported it "from rest_framework.pagination import PaginationSerializer". It's strange, I'm sure I'm doing something that is not being done in a proper way.So here is my code.

**Note:** I'm basing my code on the example on the official documentation. 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination#paginating-basic-data

Here is my TraceBack from Browser:
http://dpaste.com/2R1F03X/

Exception Type: NameError at /user-search/

Exception Value: name 'pagination' is not defined
Exception Location:     /var/www/api/serializers.py in , line 19

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.core.paginator import Paginator , EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
import json

from api.models import users, subjects
from api.serializers import PaginatedUserSerializer, UserKarmaSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def user_search(request):

    """
    Url must be example (/?subject=iOS Development)
    """

    if request.method == 'GET':

        search_subject = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('subject')

        # Query
        user_ids = subjects.objects.filter(
            ss__icontains=search_subject).values('id_user')
        user = users.objects.filter(pk__in=user_ids).order_by('-karma', 'rate')

        # Pagination Below

        paginator = Paginator(user, 20)
        page = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('page')

        try:
            user = Paginator.page(page)

        except PageNotAnInteger:
            user = Paginator.page(1)

        except EmptyPage:
            user = Paginator.page(Paginator.num_pages)

        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = PaginatedUserSerializer(user,context=serializer_context)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.pagination import PaginationSerializer
from api.models import users, chat, call, subjects



""" Search Tutors Based on Rate & Subjects """
# Below is line 19
class UserSearchSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    subjects = serializers.Field(source='user_subjects')
    user_rate = serializers.Field(source='rate_format')

    class Meta:
        model = users
        fields = ('name', 'nick', 'avatar_s', 'user_rate', 'id', 'subjects', 'bio', 'experience')


class PaginatedUserSerializer(pagination.PaginationSerializer):

    class Meta:
        object_serializer_class = UserSearchSerializer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you imported it as PaginationSerializer, you don't need pagination in front. Change to:

```
class PaginatedUserSerializer(PaginationSerializer)
```

Alternatively, you could change your import:

```
from rest_framework import pagination
```